# How to hide Form instead of closing it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

try to hide form instead of closing it, using

```
    private void Playlist_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing) //if closed by aplication
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) //if closed by user
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

but it's still close it, if User click **Close**.

Comment: The event you're capturing is `Closed`.  Try handling `Closing` instead, intercept it, cancel it, and hide instead of closing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `FormClosing` instead of `FormClosed`. There you can do `e.Cancel = true;` to achieve what you need. The problem is that the form is already **Closed** by the time `FormClosed` event occurs, so `Hide()` won't do any good and you won't be able to use this object in the future, if you try it with `FormClosed` event.

Comment: Thanks - now it's work - use `FormClosing ` - during closing prosess instead of `FormClosed` - after closing process, noted